# Web programming with higher order functions

Tags: higher-order-functions

We are learning higher-order functions in our class and our professor mentioned that they can be useful for web programming. I'm unsure as to what cases in which that would be true and was wondering if anyone had any experiences with higher-order functions in some common web programming tasks, and in what situations they would be useful.

I read through our book, but web programming wasn't mentioned, I suppose it was just something the professor mentioned off topic, but it sparked my interest a bit.

Thanks!

Comment: They are useful for *any* (take with salt, but) non-trivial programming in many paradigms (and most assuredly in the imperative -- e.g. non-declarative -- ones). "Web programming" is just a small subset of (possibly non-trivial) programming. A very trivial example of a higher-order function is applying a Map to build a list of User Names from a list of User IDs. That's not even very contrived.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure which cases your professor might have been talking about, but higher order functions are used heavily in JavaScript. A simple example of a higher order function (a function taking a function as a parameter and/or returning a function as a result) would be the jQuery ready() function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('The DOM is ready for manipulation!');
});
```

A simple example, yes...but it demonstrates how useful higher order functions can be.

Answer (score 2):

[Play](http://www.playframework.com/), ([Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)) [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) ([Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)) , [SeaSide](http://www.seaside.st/) (Smalltalk) and Webmachine ([Erlang](http://bitbucket.org/justin/webmachine/wiki/Home)) 
are three web frameworks the rely heavily on functional ideoms such as higher-order-functions.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure makes extensive use of higher order functions for web development in the excellent [Ring](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring) framework. See [this excellent video](http://blip.tv/file/4706750) which explains some of the concepts.

The basic idea is:

- A web application is really just a function that maps a request to a response
- You can therefore compose the entire web application using higher order functions